# Draw vertical line in HTML textarea at predefined column position

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Would like to draw a vertical line at a predefined column position in an HTML `textarea`.  For example, a vertical line at character position 80.  The purpose is to guide the user entering information so that they don't enter too long lines.

So, for example, here's how I would like the `textarea` to look, more or less:

[image]

Below is a code snippet to work from, though there isn't much there.

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
```

---

**UPDATE: Here is a fully implemented solution based on the accepted answer.**

This is just a simple tool I use to create comment blocks for source code.  Because of line wrapping in certain systems I'm using, I need to indicate how long of a line will produce no undesired line breaks.  But still need to allow long lines, because sometimes there's no avoiding it.

[jsfiddle.net/6brjxo1L](https://jsfiddle.net/6brjxo1L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JS to reduce textarea to 80, find out the width and make a line shift. Then increase the textarea back to 100

```js
const textareaEl = document.querySelector('.editor__textarea')
textareaEl.setAttribute('cols', 80)
const separatorLeft = textareaEl.offsetWidth

const separatorEl = document.querySelector('.editor__separator')
separatorEl.style.left = separatorLeft + 'px'
textareaEl.setAttribute('cols', 100)
```

```css
.editor {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.editor__textarea {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.editor__separator {
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <textarea class="editor__textarea" id="input" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
  <div class="editor__separator"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I posted an update to the question showing how I used your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just give it a background image using a linear gradient e.g.

```
textarea {

      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 80%, black 80% 81%, transparent 81% 100%);
    }
```

Of course set the dimensions as you require, and to give a thicker or thinner line.

Comment: If you resize textarea by width, it won't work :(

Comment: Depends on what you want it to do, that’s why I used %, are you saying that won’t then move the line? If you don’t want it to move the line then position in terms of ch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with wrapper div:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display:inline;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 97%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting with textarea attributes.

Lets look at my example.
Here I set the `cols="50"` to narrow out the textarea's width. `maxlength="300"` to limit the characters to 300. Then used `placeholder= "Max 300 characters"` to inform users that hey guys there's a limit of 300 characters so choose your words wisely. Then the `autocorrect="on"` detects incorrect spelling and provides the user with suggested correctly spelled words.

There's a ton of other attributes you can experiment with via the link I provided.

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" maxlength="200" autocorrect="on" placeholder= "Max 300 characters" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```